# Google Scripts delete duplicates from select range (not whole sheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Below is a Google Sheets script for deleting duplicate rows from a spreadsheet. While it does work in removing duplicate rows it also destroys in-cell formulas in the process. I currently have a series of sheets where all of the raw data is contained within Columns `A:P` and all of my formulas are relegated to Columns `Q:T`.

In my attempts to limit the following script to work only on Columns `A:P` I receive a missing argument error upon running the script.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getDataRange("A2:P").getValues();
```

TL:DR, I love the script, but I want to limit the range upon which it is ran. Any help? Thank you.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates

```
function removeDuplicates() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var newData = new Array();
for(i in data){
var row = data[i];
var duplicate = false;
for(j in newData){
  if(row.join() == newData[j].join()){
    duplicate = true;
  }
}
if(!duplicate){
  newData.push(row);
}
}
sheet.clearContents();
sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, 
newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

EDIT: I believe the following is above a valid question, but I would like to add a new observation that may have some impact on what's happening(??). When I initiate a find and replace from within sheets to remove all instances of the word 'null' then sheets removes null and leaves every other cell alone. However if I run a script to remove 'null' it reformats all of my cells changing dates & times to decimals. etc. Is there a means by which to run a script and avoid overall unintended actions such as sheet wide reformatting?

Comment: I <3 you dudes!  I was really struggling with my own script for deleting duplicates but a quick edit of this function to suit my spreadsheet and it works perfectly!

You really should accept the answer and give Jack props if he solved your problem!

Answer (score 5):

You will need to use [`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String)) function to specify the range on which you want to work with.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rng = sheet.getRange("A2:P")
var data = rng.getValues();
```

Also, you clear the entire sheet with this line `sheet.clearContents();` instead use this

```
rng.clearContents()
```

That way you only clear contents in the range specified by `rng`
Your final code should look like this

```
function removeDuplicates() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var rng = sheet.getRange("A2:P")
var data = rng.getValues();
var newData = new Array();
for(i in data){
var row = data[i];
var duplicate = false;
for(j in newData){
  if(row.join() == newData[j].join()){
    duplicate = true;
  }
}
if(!duplicate){
  newData.push(row);
}
}
rng.clearContents();
sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, 
newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a few years since the answer was provided. For some reason this wasn't working for me now.

I removed the "s," making `rng.clearContents();` into `rng.clearContent();`

Also the range start from row 1 to row 2 making `sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length,  newData[0].length).setValues(newData);` into `sheet.getRange(2, 1, newData.length,  newData[0].length).setValues(newData);`

Worked for me. Thank you!