# Remove duplicate values from flat ARRAY

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, duplicates

I'm wanting to remove duplicate values from the array `tabData` produced by the script below.

I've found numerous posts here that mention "removing duplicates from array", but don't seem to be relevant to my exact goal.

I've tried `filter`, I've tried using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48658311/11388717) and adjusting the variables to fit my script, but it did not remove the duplicates.

Surely there is a simple function that does exactly what I'm looking for, I'm just not finding it.

```js
function getTabArray() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var version = ss.getRangeByName("version").getValue().toString();
  var updateTabsName = "updateTabs";
  var updateTabsSheet = ss.getSheetByName(updateTabsName);

  var tabDataRows = updateTabsSheet.getLastRow();
  var tabDataCols = updateTabsSheet.getMaxColumns() - 1;
  var tabDataRange = updateTabsSheet.getRange(1, 2, tabDataRows, tabDataCols);
  var tabData = tabDataRange.getValues(); // <-- REMOVE DUPLICATES

  for (var i = 0; i < tabData.length; i++) {
    if (tabData[0][i] != "" && tabData[0][i] > version) {
      for (var j = 0; j < tabData.length; j++) {
        if (tabData[j][i] != "" && j > 0) {
          Logger.log("tabData[j][i] = " + tabData[j][i]); // tabData[j][i] = all values in column
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the array it currently produces:

```
2.20200514.2,2.20200514.0,2.20200513.2,2.20200513.1,2.20200513.0,2.20200512.0,1.20200405.1,,tabDefinitions,Sheet6,Sheet6,changeLog,Sheet6,Index,,,,Sheet7,,Sheet7,settings,,,,Sheet8,,Sheet8,tabDefinitions,,,,,,,changeLog,,,,,,,updateTabs
```

I want to remove all duplicates (Sheet6, Sheet7, Sheet8, etc.) from the array.

**EDIT:**

After one more search, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14438954/11388717) which contains exactly what was answered below, but when I use any method in that answer, I still get all duplicates.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong or not doing right.

```
var unique = tabData.filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);
```

**EDIT 2:**

I realized my array was not actually "flat", so I added `var tabData = tabDataRange.getValues().flat();` and now everything works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ES6 Set() function to remove the duplicates

```
const newArray = [...new Set(arrayWithDuplicates)];
```